# Checking the GridColumnType using a switch statement

Tags: c#

I am trying to refactor a `switch statement`. I know that you can replace a `switch` with a `Dictionary`, or a `strategy pattern` but it kind of feels like overkill for what I have.

**Switch**

```
var filters = new List<ColumnFilter>();
switch (gridColumnDataType)
                {
                    case "System.String":
                        if (filterColumnType != typeof(RuleTextNode))
                            filters.Add(columnFilter);
                        break;
                    case "System.DateTime":
                        if (filterColumnType != typeof(RuleDateNode))
                            filters.Add(columnFilter);
                        break;
                    case "System.Boolean":
                        if (filterColumnType != typeof(RuleBoolNode))
                            filters.Add(columnFilter);
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (gridColumnType.IsNumericType())
                            if (filterColumnType != typeof(RuleNumberNode))
                                filters.Add(columnFilter);
                        break;
                }
            }
```

**Explanation**

I have a grid and each grid column has its own datatype column. Like `DataType = "String.DateTime"` And there is a filter on each column. Now the problem is every now and again the filter an column does not have the same DataType. Thank you `Infragistics`.

What the switch is doing is checking what the `GridColumnType` is and if it's, let's say, a `System.String`, the `FilterColumnType` should be of type `RuleTextNode`. If it is not, I am just adding it in the `ColumnFilter` List.

All the `RuleType`s have the same underlying type `FilteringNode`.

Having said all of that, what would be the best way the rewrite the switch to avoid the code duplication and the switch?

Comment: Do these `RuleXNode`s share a base class or interface? The typical way of cleaning up the switch smell is by using polymorphism. It seems they're not your classes, so maybe an extension method is in order. You'd probably still need the switch, a solution would probably just hide it under a layer of abstraction.

Comment: @RubberDuck `All the RuleTypes has the same Underlaying type FilteringNode`. So my guess is they share a base class/interface.

Comment: Oh yeah. Hey.. Look at that there. Guess I could use another cup of coffee @Abbas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible solution I can come up with, to shorten/simplify your code, is to extract the redundant code and place it in a separate method `TryAddFilter` for example:

```
private void TryAddFilter(FilteringNode node)
{
    if (filterColumnType != typeof(node))
        filters.Add(columnFilter);
}
```

And then call this method from the switch-statement:

```
switch (gridColumnDataType)
{
    case "System.String": TryAddFilter(RuleTextNode); break;
    case "System.DateTime": TryAddFilter(RuleDateNode); break;
    case "System.Boolean": TryAddFilter(RuleBoolNode); break;
    default:
        if (gridColumnType.IsNumericType())
            TryAddFilter(RuleNumberNode); break;
}
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks, Abbas. I think is was stuck on the Dictionary and  Strategy pattern. And not seeing the obvious. This will def work for me.